# is there any way for dynamic import from node modules

Tags: import, node-modules, ace-editor, dynamic-import

i wonder is there any way to import dynamic from node-modules?
for example import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-${file}` for Ace-editor

Comment: do you use webpack or some other bundler?

Comment: I use ace editor webpack

Comment: with webpack dynamic import should work out of box. I can help to find the bug if you show me the example of not working code

Comment: i did not know that there is a webpack for it, how can i show you my exact problem?

Comment: share your code, or an example reproducing the problem on github

Comment: https://github.com/saba-bg/Ace-editor-dynamic-mode-import                                          here is the solution code,thanks

Answer (score 1):

With webpack there are two possibilities. First is to use `import()` by overwriting `ace.config.loadModule`

```
import ace from "ace-builds"
ace.config.setDefaultValue("session", "useWorker", false)
ace.config.loadModule = function(moduleName, onLoad) {
    var module, moduleType;
    if (Array.isArray(moduleName)) {
        moduleType = moduleName[0];
        moduleName = moduleName[1];
    }
    var done = m=>{
        console.log(moduleName, "loaded")
        onLoad && onLoad(m)
    };
    console.log(moduleName)
    var parts = moduleName.split("/");
    if (parts[1] == "ext") {
        import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-${parts[2]}`).then(done);
    } else if (parts[1] == "theme") {
        import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-${parts[2]}`).then(done);
    } else if (parts[1] == "mode") {
        import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-${parts[2]}`).then(done);
    } else if (parts[1] == "keyboard") {
        import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/keybinding-${parts[2]}`).then(done);
    } else if (parts[1] == "snippets") {
        import(`ace-builds/src-noconflict/snippets/${parts[2]}`).then(done);
    } else {
        console.error(moduleName, "not implemented")
    }
}
```

the second is to use file-loader by adding

```
import "ace-builds"
import "ace-builds/webpack-resolver"
```

both work with your example when added to https://github.com/saba-bg/Ace-editor-dynamic-mode-import/blob/016928b521ebc5fd5b39c52352dafddd99d9df6b/src/editor/Ace.js#L7, instead of languages.map part